# Is there anything wrong with this?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A mother is telling her ex-husband that she doesn't think he should see their son for some time because the ex-husband is dealing with some personal problems at the moment...

"I think you have enough problems to deal with right now. That's why I think it's better like this."

Hi. Is there anything wrong with "That's why I think it's better like this."? I have searched Google and it had no hits, so I was wondering if it's ungrammatical or just unnatural? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither ungrammatical nor unnatural. Not every lengthy phrase will appear in a google search, but try "it's better like this" at google books:
[Google Books](https://books.google.com/)
Put the search phrase in quotation marks to get an exact match.